# How can I simulate observations from a dynamic factor model?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, simulation, factor-analysis

Consider the following dynamic factor model where for $t = 1, 2, \ldots, T$
\begin{align}
x_t &= \Lambda f_t + e_t \quad \text{ where } e_t = \Phi_1 e_{t-1} + \epsilon_t \text{ and } \epsilon_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, \Sigma_x) \\
f_t &= \Psi_1 f_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t \quad \text{ where } \varepsilon_t \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0, \Sigma_f)
\end{align}

The observations $x_t$ are vectors with length $N$. The latent dynamic factors $f_t$ are vectors with length $K$. The matrix of factor loadings $\Lambda$ is of size $N \times K$ and the first $K \times K$ square part is lower triangular with 1's along the diagonal. The matrices of autoregressive coefficients $\Phi_1$ and $\Psi$ are diagonal and of size $N \times N$ and $K \times K$, respectively. The covariance matrices $\Sigma_x$ and $\Sigma_f$ are diagonal and of size $N \times N$ and $K \times K$, respectively. More precisely,
\begin{align}
\Phi_1 &= \text{diag} (\phi_{11}, \dots, \phi_{1N}) \\
\Psi_1 &= \text{diag} (\psi_{11}, \dots, \psi_{1K}) \\
\Sigma_x &= \text{diag} (\sigma_{x1}^2, \ldots, \sigma_{xN}^2) \\
\Sigma_f &= \text{diag} (\sigma_{f1}^2, \ldots, \sigma_{fK}^2) \\
\Lambda &= 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ \lambda_{21} & 1 \\ \lambda_{31} & \lambda_{32} \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ \lambda_{N1} & \lambda_{N2} \end{bmatrix} \text{ for example if } K = 2
\end{align}

The prior distributions are 
\begin{align}
\phi_{1i} &\overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0,1) \text{ for } i = 1,\ldots, N \\
\psi_{1j} &\overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0,1) \text{ for } j = 1,\ldots, K \\
\lambda_{nk} &\overset{iid}{\sim} \mathcal{N} (0,1) \text{ for the lower triangular part of } \Lambda \\
\sigma_{xi}^2 &\overset{iid}{\sim} \text{inv-}\chi^2 (\nu = 4, \tau^2 = 0.01) \text{ for } i = 1,\ldots, N \\
\sigma_{fj}^2 &\overset{iid}{\sim} \text{inv-}\chi^2 (\nu = 4, \tau^2 = 0.01) \text{ for } j = 1,\ldots, K
\end{align}

> **Question:** How can I simulate/generate observations according to this model? That is, how can I obtain $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_T$?

**My thoughts:**
I am new to simulations in general. The process described below seems to be the most obvious. While I believe my thought process to be logical, I don't really have a way to make sure that it is correct as most texts involving models of this nature use real datasets.

1. Simulate model parameters according to their prior distributions.
2. Simulate $\varepsilon_t$ from $\mathcal{N} (0, \Sigma_f)$ for $t = 1, \ldots, T$.
3. Simulate $f_0$ from $\mathcal{N} (0, A_f)$ where $A_f$ comes from some fixed point equation (idea comes from [Bayesian Core](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-38983-7)).
4. Simulate $f_t$ from $\mathcal{N} (\Psi_1 f_{t-1}, \Sigma_f)$ for $t = 1, \ldots, T$
5. Simulate $e_0$ from $\mathcal{N} (0, A_x)$ where $A_x$ comes from some fixed point equation.
6. Simulate $e_t$ from $\mathcal{N} (\Phi_1 e_{t-1}, \Sigma_f)$ for $t = 1, \ldots, T$.
7. Obtain $x_t$ using $\Lambda f_t + e_t$.

---

Based on the help from @IsabellaGhement, I came up with the following code that I think does what I am looking for.

```
library(tsDyn) #for the function 'VAR.sim'
library(lgarch) #for the function 'rmnorm' that is used in the function 'VAR.sim'

set.seed(3)
N <- 250 #number of variables
TT <- 150 #number of time series observations
K <- 5 #number of hidden factors

# specify all the model parameters
sigma.X <- phi <- 0.5 * diag(N)
sigma.F <- psi <- 0.3 * diag(K)
lambda <- matrix( rep( 0, times = N * K ), nrow = N, ncol = K )
lambda[1:K, 1:K] <- diag(K) #turns the first square into the identity matrix
lambda[lower.tri(lambda)] <- rnorm( K * (K - 1) / 2 + (N - K) * K ) #fills lower triangular parts with values from the normal distribution

#generate idiosyncratic components, e_t
e <- VAR.sim( B = phi, n = TT, include = "none", 
            innov = rmnorm(TT, mean = rep(0, TT), vcov = sigma.X), 
            varcov = sigma.X )

#generate the latent factors, f_t
f <- VAR.sim( B = psi, n = TT, include = "none", 
            innov = rmnorm(TT, mean = rep(0, TT), vcov = sigma.F), 
            varcov = sigma.F )

#generate observations, x_t
obs <- lambda %*% t(f) + t(e)
```

Comment: Cool! I will play with this in the next few days to build some intuition for what it does. Thank you so much for sharing your code. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package *bayesdfa* in R has a function called sim_dfa() which simulates data from a dynamic factor model, so you can look into its bowels to get some ideas for how you can simulate data for this type of model:

```
install.packages("bayesdfa")

library(bayesdfa)

set.seed(1)

sim_dat <- sim_dfa(
   num_trends = 2, 
   num_years = 20,
   num_ts = 4
)
```

Just use the command edit(sim_dfa) to access the function definition. Also, see the *bayesdfa* package vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesdfa/vignettes/bayesdfa.html.

Another detailed example of simulating data for this type of model can be found in this post on Dynamic Factor Analysis with the greta package for R:

https://mdscheuerell.github.io/gretaDFA/

Comment: Both sources assume that the factors evolve as a Guassian random walk. I'm having trouble altering the code of the sim_dfa function so that the factors evolve as an VAR(1) process, but I keep ending up with NaNs.

Comment: Would something like this help: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsDyn/versions/0.8-1/topics/VAR.sim?

Comment: I think it does! I can simulate $f_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \ldots, T$ using 'VAR.sim' and do the same thing to simulate $e_t$ for $t = 1, 2, \ldots, T$. Then use the results to obtain the observations.

Comment: That's great to hear! You've made rapid progress with just a few suggestions! 

Comment: If you are happy with your R code, can you share it here in an answer to your own question? This way, others can learn alongside you.

Comment: Most definitely. Will add it once I obtain something that runs successfully.

Comment: I fixed the problem. 1) I should just fix the model parameter values instead of simulating them according to the prior distributions I mentioned in the OP. 2) The documentation has a misprint in the arguments of the 'VAR.sim' function.

Comment: 'innov=rmnorm(n, mean=0, varcov=varcov)' should actually be 'innov=rmnorm(n, mean=0, $\bf vcov$=varcov)'